# How to back to previous view in tab bar?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I have a tab bar controller as the root view, there are 5 tabs.
every tab has a view controller.

With this situation:
When i browse view in tab 1, then click the center tab to show a view, this view has a back button in it's navigation bar, when i click the back button, it back to tab 1 view;
When i browse view in tab 2, the same flow to click back button, then back to tab 2 view;

This similar with the instagram app on ios.
when click post tab(the center tab), it shows a view to take picture, when i click cancel button on that view, it back to previous view in previous tab.

My question is: how do I implement the back button?

I'v searched hours and no solutions.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: one every tab instead of using ViewController use UINavigationtionController then it will solve your problem

Comment: @MuhammadWaqas   I think the solution is presenting view controllers : )